# Wait a few ajax finished, but the ajax function is dynamically called

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to wait a few ajax finished.
I have checked some pages and get the ideas of

`$.when ().done(funciton(){})....`

However in my case is little bit complex.
ajax is dynamically generated and, it is the method of the Class.

```
class TestClass{
    constructor(){} 
    myAjax = function(id){
        $.ajax({
            url:  myajax,
            type: 'POST',dataType: 'json',
            data: {"id" : id},
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("byId loaded:"+ id);
            }
        });
    }
}
testclass = new TestClass();
var myIds = [1,3,5,7];
for (var i in myIds) {
    testclass.myAjax(myIds[i]); // I want to wait every ajax is finished.
}
```

I have tried like this using $.when() but in vain (compile error)

```
$.when(
for (var i in myIds) {
    testclass.callGraph(myIds[i]); .

).done(function(){
    console.log("load finished");
}
```

Comment: Classes and jQuery? Not great mix. Right time for fetch() and Promise.all().

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class TestClass{
    constructor(){} 
    myAjax = function(id){
        return $.ajax({
            url:  myajax,
            type: 'POST',dataType: 'json',
            data: {"id" : id},
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("byId loaded:"+ id);
            }
        });
    }
}
testclass = new TestClass();
var promises = [];
var myIds = [1,3,5,7];
for (var i in myIds) {
    promises.push(testclass.myAjax(myIds[i])); // I want to wait every ajax is finished.
}

$.when(promises).then(function(values){
   console.log('all ajax request completed');
});
```

Comment: I have tried like this but,it returns `all ajax request completed` immediately, not waiting for ajax finished.

Comment: What do you mean by `finished` here. My understanding is that after all promise object resolve ( pending to finished state) then $.when called